# hibernate inner join question

Tags: hibernate

I have a question in hibernate HQL query with HQL.
I have two entities one is Notes and other is NotesEmp class which has one to one relation ship.
my notes class looks like the following

```
class Notes{
  private BigDecimal noteId;
  private String notes; 
      @Id
    @Column
    @GenericGenerator

    public BigDecimal getNoteId() {
        return noteId;
    }

    public void setNoteId(BigDecimal noteId) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
    }

       @Lob
    @Column
    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }
}
```

where as the other entiry looks like the following

```
public class PfmNote implements Serializable{


    private BigDecimal noteId;

    private String accountId;


    private String noteType;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//one to one relation ship with Note
    @JoinColumn
    public Notes getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(Notes note) {
        this.note = note;
    }    

       //with other columsn with setter and gretter method

}
```

Now i have an HQL query in my configuration file which looks like the following

```
<query name="getETNoteForPortfolio">                  
    <![CDATA[ from packagename.Notes n,packagename.PortfolioNote p 
               where n.noteId=p.noteId and n.noteId=:noteId]]>
</query>
```

Now

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("getETNoteForPortfolio",
                                                     "noteId", 
                                                     new BigDecimal(noteId));
```

which is returning a list of obeject...
How can we iterate the list and get al the entires from there.
I would really appreciate if some one have any suggesiton.

Thanks in advance